# adding a method to an existing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, controller, action

I'm pretty new to rails, and I'm hoping you can help me understand how the following works.

At present I have a controller named projects (projects_controller.rb). From what I understand of ROR each controller has some basic (inherent) methods such as index, new, create, edit, show, etc.  I would like to add a method called "help" and a view to display the help information.

At present a user can create many projects. The projects contain a set of fields that are populated by the user. I would like to add a help page that the user can access (via a link on the project screen) which explains each project field and how to best fill it out. I would like this to be an independent page (not just info displayed on the project's page).

As of now, the URL to the projects is (when editing a project): **localhost:3001/projects/id/edit**

I would like for the path to the help file to be **localhost:3001/projects/id/help**

If I want the help file to be located in the path listed above, am I correct in assuming that I need to create a new method, called "help", in the projects controller? And if so, is there something that I need to add to routes.rb to make it function? And would I use a link_to function in the Haml to create a link to it?

I'm sorry if this seems confusing or a lot of question. I appreciate your time. If you have any suggestions on whether on the right path please let me know. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think currently you  have this in routes

```
resources :products do  

end
```

just replace this with

```
resources :products do  
  get :help, :on => :member, :as => :help  
end
```

And add method in controller and add view named help.erb.html(if you r using erb) in views/product folder.

you can use help_path and help_url

Comment: Dnyan, thanks so much... this has helped tremendously! My only question now is with linking to help.html.haml from another view. the help_path does not work... could it be because I don't have a help controller? It's simply a method in an existing (projects) controller. Thanks so much for all of your help thus far!

Comment: use products_help_path and products_help_url